# Need to unplug and replug my headphones after every reboot

Tags: headphones

Basically, every time I turn on my machine, I need to plug off and replug my headphones every time. If I don't do this, sound does not come out of my headphones but out of my laptop.

I have no idea what command to write in the terminal as I'm a beginner, if you can help me I would be glad.

Comment: It's how your hardware works and frankly not a problem.

Comment: Frankly it is a problem @ChanganAuto . Windows seem to remember the channel used on the device. I don't see why linux has to forget, and the attitude of "it's not linux's problem" isn't the right one to allow linux to get a good UX.